# JS simple function in function won't work

Tags: javascript, function

I wanted to make this 1 function and call it in function 2.

```
function d6Roll(){
            var d6 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            }
function attackModifier(){
                d6Roll();
                var aMod = d6;
                document.getElementById("rezultatD6").innerHTML = aMod;
            }
```

For some reason it works only like this:

```
function d6Roll(){
            var d6 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            document.getElementById("rezultatD6").innerHTML = d6;
            }
```

Is it possible that function can't go inside another function?

Comment: Problem solved, sorry for bothering you people with basics i obviously missed >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change the first function to this

```
function d6Roll(){
  return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
}
```

so that you can call it in the second function like this

```
function attackModifier(){
  var aMod = d6Roll();
  document.getElementById("rezultatD6").innerHTML = aMod;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible that function cant go in another function?

It is completely possible, you're just doing it incorrectly. Variables can't 'escape' their scope (in this case, the function that they're inside), so you can't access  `d6` from the `attackModifier` function. Instead, return the value, like so:

```
function d6Roll(){
    return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
}
```

You can then get the value of the roll like this:

```
function attackModifier(){
    var aMod = d6Roll();
    document.getElementById("rezultatD6").innerHTML = aMod;
}
```

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) might have some useful explanation about how function returns work.

Answer (score 1):

For you get the `d6` variable in the `attackModifier` function, you need create this variable outside of `d6Roll` function.

Look like:

```
var d6;

function d6Roll() {  ... }
function attackModifier() {...}
```

Comment: I find others solutions better but what you wrote here will be crucial for me later, I guess I'll have to investigate private/global variables in JS for this project and further, thank you :)

Comment: While this approach will certainly work (under strict conditions) it seems like a bad idea to actively encourage a bad practice like this, no?

Comment: Yes, this is not a good practice, dependency the situation, maybe can put the code in the IIFE to make private